# batch-processing PDFs with automated edits

Tags: open-source, software-development, text-editor, automation, pdf-editor

I have 100 pdfs. All of them have a portion at two parts within them which I want to hide. ALSO, I have to put a .jpg image at a fixed position (in all pdfs). The image  is different in all pdfs. The images are renamed such that their names get matched by a word in the pdf (e.g. if the image is named as cat.jpg,  the word cat is contained in the pdf only once). Lastly, I want a screenshot of the final (edited) pdf.  I can easily do this process using xodo.

BUT, it consumes a lot of time as I can edit only one such pdf at a time. It takes about 1 min for 1 pdf which implies that it would take 100 min for 100 pdfs.   So, I want to automate this whole process just by uploading somewhere (e.g. into a software or a web application) and get everything done within seconds.. ;)

Comment: If this is a one of thing, that it will be faster for you to do it manually.  100mins is nothing compared to learning curve for a new application or the time in writing one.

Comment: In the time you invested to search for, check answers, test suggestions and learn to use each of the pieces, you'd most likeky have manually processed more than 500 of your PDFs – in this I fully agree with Rohit. Apart from that, if you still want such software, mind telling us on what OS it should run?

Comment: Its not just about one time or a day. I have to do this task (to edit 100 pdfs in such way) everyday. I want such software for windows.

Comment: Or is this a machine learning related problem?? plz reply...